# How to add endpoints in dropwizard like /healthcheck

Tags: dropwizard, kubernetes-health-check

we can add healthcheck like

```
environment.healthChecks().register(
   CheckpointConstant.CACHE,
   new CacheHealthCheck(adminConfiguration.getAppName())
);
```

but these are all in the '/healthcheck' interface.

how to add endpoints in port 8081, like '/healthcheck';e.g. '/liveness'.

Comment: Check here: https://howtodoinjava.com/dropwizard/health-check-configuration-example/ You are interested in the part titled `Custom REST Resource to Run Health Checks`. They use the `/status` endpoint URL, but you should get the idea :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dropwizard : New admin resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764337/dropwizard-new-admin-resource)

Comment: In the link you posted they explain how to add healthcheck like resource to the app port, he's interested in adding an endpoint to the admin app.

Comment: I have the suspicion they don't need the `admin` app separation (or they are aware that it is not exactly necessary). Also I've just found this: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-health It's a recently new official module for `dropwizard`. There is a configuration value for the healtcheck URL.